# allauth isn't sending verification email

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using [django allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/) for my user accounts. I'm using the default settings, except for the following:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
```

which have all been set in my `settings.py` file.

When I create an account, it successfully tells me it will send an email to the address for verification. However I don't receive this email.

I'm not sure if my django email backend is not working (how do I check if it is?) or if my allauth settings are not configured properly. My django site is running on a remote Ubuntu server with Nginx/Gunicorn.

Any idea?

Comment: To send mail with the SMTP backend you need to actually have access to a SMTP server, and [configure your settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#smtp-backend) to use it.

Comment: It's always recommended to set up an SMTP server (ref. link by @KevinChristopherHenry); For development purposes you can use : `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`, which prints 
 any outgoing email to console.